# A basic Rock, Paper or Scissors program

Tags: python

Updated code:

```
  #RockPS
import random

Choices=['R','P','S']
UserScore=0
CpuScore=0
Games=0

while Games<6:
    UserChoice=input('Rock, paper or scissors? (Type R, P or S respectively)')
    if UserChoice in Choices:
        Games+=1
CpuChoice = random.choice(Choices)   

if UserChoice == 'S' and CpuChoice == 'P':
    UserScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'P' and CpuChoice == 'R':
    UserScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'R' and CpuChoice == 'S':
    UserScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'S' and CpuChoice == 'R':
    CpuScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'P' and CpuChoice == 'S':
    CpuScore+=1
if UserChoice == 'R' and CpuChoice == 'P':
    CpuScore+=1

else:
    print('Only R, P or S are allowed')


print(UserScore, CpuScore)
if UserScore>CpuScore:
    print('Well done, you won!')
if UserScore==CpuScore:
    print('You tied!')
if UserScore<CpuScore:
    ('Unlucky, you lost.')
```

There is still one problem. When the scores are printed it only every says 1 0 either way, assumingly to the player with the majority of wins. It should count each game, e.g 3 2 or 4 1

Comment: The prompt isn't inside the loop; also you never increment the Games counter

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Here's some rewritten code for your benefit, to help introduce to you some new concepts you will want to get familiar with as a new programmer in python. http://ideone.com/xFTgA  With the comments, it should help demonstrate the use of a dictionary for scores, the xrange generator, and how to reduce the logic tree of who wins RPS. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, other Py3k rock paper scissors help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rock+paper+scissors+%5Bpython-3.x%5D&submit=search

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the only problems, but what jumps out at me right away: The line

```
random.choice(CpuChoice)
```

does not set CpuChoice to a random choice for the computer. random.choice() returns a random choice, but you don't store it anywhere. You want

```
CpuChoice = random.choice(['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'])
```

...and you want to do that (and collect user input, and probably output the outcome of each individual round) inside your loop, unless the CPU plays the same choice every time, which will make it pretty easy to defeat :)

Also you never increment Games anywhere -- actually, instead of a while loop there, you probably want a for-loop since you just want to run the body 6 times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to input *inside* your loop. Don't forget to increment the number of games played.

Comment: ...also, the 'Games' variable is never incremented, so the loop will go forever.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code:

1. You are not using `random.choice` properly.
2. You should call that function every time before the user plays. If you call it once, it will stay the same each time.
3. The user is asked to enter a value once because the `input(...)` function is called once **outside** of the loop.
4. This is not the way to name your variables (at least in Python)
5. Using if/elif many times to do the same thing is not the way use `or`

So, your code should look like that:

```
#RockPS
import random

game_choices = ['R','P','S']
user_score = 0
cpu_score = 0
games = 0

while games<6:
    user_choice = input('Rock, paper or scissors? (Type R, P or S respectively)')
    if user_choice in game_choices:
        games += 1
        cpu_choice = random.choice(cpu_choices)
        if (user_choice == 'S' and cpu_choice == 'P') or \
           (user_choice == 'P' and cpu_choice == 'R') or \
           (user_choice == 'R' and cpu_choice == 'S'):
            user_score += 1
        elif (user_choice == 'S' and cpu_choice == 'R') or \
             (user_choice == 'P' and cpu_choice == 'S') or \
             (user_choice == 'R' and cpu_choice == 'P'):
            cpu_score += 1
    else:
        print('Only R, P or S are allowed')

print(user_score, cpu_score)
if user_score>cpu_score:
    print('Well done, you won!')
elif user_score == cpu_score:
    print('You tied!')
elif user_score<cpu_score:
    print('Unlucky, you lost.')
```

You can still improve it. I added a check to make sure the letters are either RPS. And this big chunk of conditions, you could make them shorter by using a function that returns the winner (e.g. 1 if cpu won and 0 if player won), etc...

Comment: You can make the chunk of conditions even shorter and reduce room for error by identifying ties, and user wins and then all else conditions are cpu wins (see my comment to OP)

Comment: Thanks. I've manipulated this a bit but I still have a problem. When the scores are published it only ever says 1 0 either way. It should be 3 2 or 4 1 or 5 0 or even 2 2 if their is a draw. My updated is code in the original post.

Comment: @user1331579 Be careful with indentation !!! It's very important that you keep the same indentation level (or more) from `while game<6:` to `print('Only ...')`. This is the equivalent of `{ ... }` in other languages (if you're familiar with that). In other words, the code that is not indented after the `CpuChoice = ...` part in your code will not be executed in the while loop, but instead will run once, and update the score once ONLY!

Comment: @hexparrot yes, I said it could be improved A LOT, but I tried to limit the answer as much as possible...

Comment: My apologies; I didn't mean to criticize your code; simply to bring attention to the potential ease of logic-trees I provided in a comment for the OP since this was the highest rated post at the time.

Comment: @hexparrot sorry if I seemed rude, I had already understood what you meant :) nevermind...

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fixed it for you.

I tried to mimic your style, and keep what I can in place, in order to allow you to see what changes werde made.
That said: that style is generally discouraged, see jadkik94's answer for better style.
Maybe I'll rewrite this Program later, in an edit. If I find time.

```
import random
CpuChoices=['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
PlayerChoices = dict(zip("RPS", CpuChoices))
UserScore=0
CpuScore=0
Games=0
while Games<6:
    UserChoice=input('Rock, paper or scissors? (Type R, P or S respectively)')
    if UserChoice not in PlayerChoices: continue
    CpuChoice = random.choice(CpuChoices)

    if UserChoice=='S' and CpuChoice=='Paper':
        UserScore+=1
    elif UserChoice=='P' and CpuChoice=='Rock':
        UserScore+=1
    elif UserChoice=='R' and CpuChoice=='Scissors':
        UserScore+=1

    if UserChoice=='S' and CpuChoice=='Rock':
        CpuScore+=1 
    elif UserChoice=='P' and CpuChoice=='Scissors':
        CpuScore+=1
    elif UserChoice=='R' and CpuChoice=='Paper':
        CpuScore+=1
    print("CPU chose %s against your %s" % (CpuChoice, PlayerChoices[UserChoice]))
    print("User: %s - CPU: %s" % (UserScore, CpuScore))
    Games += 1

if UserScore > CpuScore:
    print('Well done, you won!')
if UserScore == CpuScore:
    print('You tied!')
if UserScore < CpuScore:
    print('Unlucky, you lost.')

print("the only winning move it not to play")
```

as promised, here is the code how I'd have written it (well, not really, but... you get the idea):

```
import random

class RSPHand(object):
    names = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
    beats = {
            'Rock': 'Scissors',
            'Scissors': 'Paper',
            'Paper': 'Rock',
            }
    def __init__(self, name):
        if name not in self.__class__.names:
            try:
                name = [n for n in self.__class__.names if n[0] == name.upper()][0]
            except IndexError:
                raise ValueError ("Name not valid")
        self.name = name
        self.shortname = self.name[0]
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return other.name == self.__class__.beats[self.name]
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.name == self.__class__.beats[other.name]

choices=[]
for name in RSPHand.names:
    choices.append(RSPHand(name))


playerscore = cpuscore = 0

while True:
    rounds = input("Best out of how many rounds? ")
    try:
        rounds = int(rounds)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    break

while rounds:
    playerchoice = input("%s? (Type first letter, lowercase or not, or full name) " % [choice.name for choice in choices])
    try:
        playerchoice = RSPHand(playerchoice)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    cpuchoice = random.choice(choices)
    print ("CPU chose %s against your %s" % (cpuchoice, playerchoice))
    if playerchoice < cpuchoice:
        cpuscore += 1
        print("too bad for you")
    elif playerchoice > cpuchoice:
        playerscore += 1
        print("too bad for CPU")
    else:
        print("that's a tie for this round")
    print ("CPU: %s - Player: %s" % (cpuscore, playerscore))
    rounds -= 1

if playerscore > cpuscore:
    print('Well done, you won!')
elif playerscore == cpuscore:
    print('You tied!')
elif playerscore < cpuscore:
    print('Unlucky, you lost.')
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'd rather stick to what I know for now. You're using stuff I'm yet to learn yet. I've altered my original answer in the OP. It works, apart from I can't get the score output to show the real score. It'll only ever be 1 0, 0 0, or 0 1. How would I get it to show all the game scores from my code? Thanks.

Comment: your whole game logic apart from asking the user is outside the loop. So you basically ask 6 times for input, but only use it once. Put all the stuff that belongs there inside the loop, and it should work.